# ASP.NET MVC post controller get json, generate file and return it

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, post

I have an ajax post request:

```
  function downloadElevationMap() {
    var jsonData = ko.toJSON(mod.SelectedItem);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetData/',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("OK");
        },
    });
}
```

The controller method recive data correct. The code is presented below:

```
public FileStreamResult GetData(Mv jsonData)
        {
            var resultAll = jsonData.Data.Select(d => d.y).ToList();
            var str = new StringBuilder();
            _fileName = "ses"+jsonData.Path;
            foreach (var d in resultAll)
            {
                str.Append(d + " ");
            }
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString());
            var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            return File(stream, "text/plain", string.Format("{0}.txt", _fileName));
        }
```

Mv - is my class that represent data. When debug the both `str` and stream `variable` contain correct data.

Function `downloadElevationMap()` is called by `onclick="downloadElevationMap()"`

I just want when `downloadElevationMap()` is called the `GetData` controller return a file for download. But simply nothing happend. Where the error is?

Comment: That isn't actually JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: this will be the best solution for you....... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7660817/1068147

Answer (score 2):

well you dont need ajax to do that try this

```
window.location="download.action?para1=value1...."
```

for your needs you can do some thing like this

```
window.location="/Home/GetData/?"+$.param(jsonData )
```

Comment: But my jsonData is really huge. It is impossible to pass it in that way, i think. Another problen that file for downloading generates depends on jsonData.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure what you are doing is swallowing the data in the success callback in the AJAX call - all your code will do is download the file, call the `success` callback, and then just print "OK" to the console.

As Anto said, you don't need AJAX (and, indeed, should not be using AJAX) for this. His answer is absolutely correct, provided you can use a GET string. If you need to use a POST request, create a form with hidden inputs and submit that - something like:

**HTML**

```
<form action="/Home/GetData" method="POST" id="dataToSubmit">
   <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="value2" />
   <input type="hidden" name="param3.param4" value="value3" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function downloadElevationMap() {
  // Write code to map your jsonData to your form elements

  $('#dataToSubmit').submit();
}
```

You could make the form dynamically if you wish. You might be able to update your page to post directly with a submit button.

One final note, you don't need to submit the data as Json. If you have

```
{
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": "value2",
    "param3": {
        "param4": "value3"
    }
}
```

then if you just use the format in the form above, it will submit fine - [this reference](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/) explains how to submit to deep models.